# Should I separate customers into separate VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

**Use Case:** I will have a separate ec2 instance for each client - all of the instances will host identical web apps and db (at the moment, I'm keeping the db in the ec2 instance and not breaking it out).

If I am trying to provide security for each client, would you recommend creating a separate VPC for each ec2 instance, even if they are in the same region? Or would that be overkill?

Thanks! So far, I have not been able to find this on multiple google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Isolating Resources in a Multi-Tenant Environment](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/saas-tenant-isolation-strategies.pdf) from AWS.

Comment: Thanks, jarmod. This is exactly what I needed. Basically..."it depends".  But this doc gave me the info I need to decide.